# Why is reverse of a number c program written with the concept of digits places instead like the below one which I posted?

Tags: c, numbers, reverse

```
void rev(int n){
        int rem;
        printf("reverse of that number is:");
        while(n>0)
        {
            rem=n%10;
            n=n/10;
            printf("%d",rem);
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        printf("enter a number of more than two digits");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        rev(n);
        return 0;
    }
```

This code without writing a piece of code for digits places i.e.,

```
reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
```

also returns the same. 
please explain if there is any mistake in my perspective.
regards.

Comment: Coul you try to phrase your question a bit more clear? `rev` does not actually calculate the reverse number it only prints it. Also note that if you reverse an integer it could be out of `int` range.

Comment: The `rev()` function does not reverse the number. Please check

Comment: A single statement is no code. Please provide a complete sample or at least a complete function. The variables are not defined. What should they contain? How should it get there? When will the loop stop....

Comment: Doesn’t produce the same output without extra work when the number ends with zeros.

Comment: Regarding the question title, what is the reverse of `100`? It is the same reason why we store telephone and card numbers as strings, not integers: any leading zeros are significant and unless they are stated *you don't know how many there are*.

Comment: rev fails for 0.  It should be `do .. while`.

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you actually didn't reverse number, you are just printing it. If you want to store reversed number and use it later, you have to to do `reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;`

Answer (score 0):

What will you do if someone ask you to add a integer **X** with the reverse of the given number? Counting the reverse number always is a good idea than just printing it form last digit to first. This small change in your code may be very useful:

```
void rev(long long n){
    long long rem = 0;
    printf("reverse of that number is:");
    while(n>0)
    {
        rem= rem*10+(n%10);
        n=n/10;
    }
    printf("%lld",rem);
}
```

Here you can also return the value of ***rem*** for further use.

**UPDATE:**

As @Weather Vane says, what if user want to see the reverse number with leading zeros(if there any), the only way then to input the number as string. and reverse it. A string can reverse using **strrev()** function from `<string.h>`

```
strrev(string_name);
```

If it is a *STL String* than using **reverse()** function from `<algorithm>` will be useful.

```
reverse(string_name.begin(), string_name.end());
```

If you want to get the *integer from the string* you can do this like this:

```
long long str_to_num(string s)
{
    long long integer = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        integer = integer*10+(s[i]-'0');
    }
    return integer;
}
```

Comment: But be careful, not every `int` can be reversed this way, for example `1000000009` would lead to an `int` overflow.

Comment: you can use **long long** in that case. and if it overflow the long long than using string is the obvious way

Comment: Yes, if `long long` is wider than `int` it can not overflow, it was just a side node to your solution.

Comment: @NiloyRashid you have only addressed the actual question (see its title) in your comment. Your solution will give the reverse of `100` as `1`, not `001`.

Comment: @Weather Vane if you want those leading zero's and still want to use the reverse number than using string is the only way

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I posted my other comment under the question, earlier. Are you sure you know what OP was asking?

Comment: You make a good point @WeatherVane. I update the answer. Thank You brother